# Regex multiple filters

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Need help with a regex to select multiple lines. From what I have so far it works until I put the last regex in. Once I do that, it skips over the middle one. Passwords have been removed for security purposes.

**My Goals**

1. Select all lines beginning at Current configuration ending at
   version, "or the ! right before it"
2. Select all lines with "secret"
3. Select all lines with "password"

**My Regex**

```
(?s)Current configuration (.*)NVRAM|secret 5 +(\S+)|password 7 +(\S+)
```

**EDIT: took about spaces before and after the | and it seems to highlight what i want. It doesn't do the entire line though.**

**Test Data**

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 45617 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 00:22:36 UTC Sun Jan 22 2017 by user
! NVRAM config last updated at 00:22:43 UTC Sun Jan 22 2017 by user
!
version 15.0
no service pad
!
no logging console
enable secret 5 ***encrypted password***
!
username admin privilege 15 password 7 ***encrypted password***
username sadmin privilege 15 secret 5 ***encrypted password***
aaa new-model
!
ip ftp username ***encrypted password***
ip ftp password 7 ***encrypted password***
ip ssh version 2
!
line con 0
 password 7 ***encrypted password***
 login authentication maint
line vty 0 4
 password 7 ***encrypted password***
 length 0
 transport input ssh
line vty 5 15
 password 7 ***encrypted password***
 transport input ssh
!
```

**Desired Result:**

```
Building configuration...

!
version 15.0
no service pad
!
no logging console
enable 
!
username admin privilege 15 
username gisadmin privilege 15 
aaa new-model
!
ip ftp username cfgftp
ip ftp 
ip ssh version 2
!
line con 0

 login authentication maint
line vty 0 4

 length 0
 transport input ssh
line vty 5 15

 transport input ssh
!
```

Comment: are you using global? it seems to be working how you have it if you use the global flag https://regex101.com/r/TyT1Mp/1

Comment: did you try without regex ?

Comment: Replace `(.*)` with `(.*?)`

Comment: @maksymiuk I removed the spaces before the | and it seems to be selecting what i need now. do you know how to use re.sub(). I'm basically trying to use this regex to then replace it with an empty string " ".

Comment: Whats the final desired result? Can you also include that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This Should Work.**

**REGEXP:**

```
((?:\bCurrent configuration)(?:.*\n?){6})$|((?:\bsecret)(?:.)+$)|((?:\bpassword\s)(?:.)+$)
```

**INPUT:**

Building configuration...

```
Current configuration : 45617 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 00:22:36 UTC Sun Jan 22 2017 by user
! NVRAM config last updated at 00:22:43 UTC Sun Jan 22 2017 by user
!
version 15.0
no service pad
!
no logging console
enable secret 5 ***encrypted password***
!
username admin privilege 15 password 7 ***encrypted password***
username sadmin privilege 15 secret 5 ***encrypted password***
aaa new-model
!
ip ftp username ***encrypted password***
ip ftp password 7 ***encrypted password***
ip ssh version 2
!
line con 0
 password 7 ***encrypted password***
 login authentication maint
line vty 0 4
 password 7 ***encrypted password***
 length 0
 transport input ssh
line vty 5 15
 password 7 ***encrypted password***
 transport input ssh
!
```

**OUTPUT:**

**Group: $1:**

```
Current configuration : 45617 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 00:22:36 UTC Sun Jan 22 2017 by user
! NVRAM config last updated at 00:22:43 UTC Sun Jan 22 2017 by user
!
version 15.0
```

**GROUP $2:**

```
enable secret 5 ***encrypted password***
```

**GROUP $3:**

```
password 7 ***encrypted password***
password 7 ***encrypted password***
password 7 ***encrypted password***
password 7 ***encrypted password***
password 7 ***encrypted password***
```

**See:** https://regex101.com/r/NOrndn/1

**Test Python Code:** http://ideone.com/UyjT38

Comment: I i modified the regex to just have secret instead of enable secret and this does exactly what i want. Thank you.